# Does anyone know of a good expression for this Maclaurin series?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, lagrange-inversion

I'm looking for a usable (something I can program) closed form or recursive formula for the coefficients $a_n$ of this series for an even-symmetry function of a real variable:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n} = \frac{x}{\arctan(x)} $$

for $\big|x\big| \le 1$ .

Ultimately, what I want is an expression like

$$ \arctan(x) = \frac{x}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n}} $$

again, for $\big|x\big| \le 1$ .

I've approached this both from the POV of Taylor/Maclaurin series and tried to get a grip of using the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), but am not getting to an elegant place.

$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n} &= \frac{x}{\arctan(x)} \\
\\
&= \frac{x}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1}} \\
\\
&= \frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k}} \\
\end{align}$$

or

$$ \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n u^n \right) \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} u^k  \right) = 1 $$

for $0 \le u \le 1$ .

I get this:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} u^{k+n} = 1 $$

and

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n  \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-2n+1} u^{k} = 1 $$

I can see right away that $a_0 = 1$, but I should be able to yank out a recursion formula out of this.  But I forgot how to do that.  All of the net coefficients of the higher powers of $u^k$ should be $0$ for $k \ge 1$.

---

Denouement:

It's simpler than I thought.

So we have

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} u^{k+n} = 1 $$

Let's let the exponent of $u$ be fixed to some integer $m \ge 0$.  So $n+k=m$ and, for a given $n$, the only term in the inner summation that counts for the coefficient of $u^m$ is $k=m-n$.

We know for $m=0$ the summation is $1$.

$$ a_n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} u^{k+n} \Big|_{n=k=0} = 1 $$

which results in $a_0=1$.  For all other $m\ge 1$, the summation is

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{m} a_n \frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{2(m-n)+1} u^m = 0 \qquad \forall u: 0 \le u \le 1$$

or

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{m} a_n \frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{2(m-n)+1} = 0$$

Spinning off the last term for

$$ a_m + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{m-1} a_n \frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{2(m-n)+1} = 0 $$

or

$$ a_m =  -\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m-1} a_n \frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{2(m-n)+1} $$

I confess that I didn't read the reference, I just needed to look at this more clearly.  I guess with the additional substitution of $k=m-n$ we get:

$$ a_m =  -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} a_{m-k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} $$

.

Comment: You could find the coefficients in sequences $A216272$ and $A195466$ in $OEIS$.

Comment: i must confess that i have absolutely no idea what you mean here, @ClaudeLeibovici.

Comment: Visit OEIS and type the name of the sequence.

Comment: well, i learn something new every day.  had never heard of this **On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences** before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of handling this. Note that

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n} \arctan(x) &= x \implies \\
\\
\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n}\right)\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1}\right) &= x \\
\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{2n}\right)\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k}\right) &= 1 \\
\end{align}

Then you can expand and equate coefficients:

\begin{align}
a_0\cdot 1 &= 1 \implies a_0=1\\
(a_1-a_0/3)\cdot x^2 &= 0 \implies a_1=1/3\\
\vdots
\end{align}

---

Another way, from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53402):

$$a_0 = 1$$

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k+1}a_{n-k}$$

Special thanks to Sangchul Lee for changing the indices nicely.

Comment: is there a general form for the recursion of $a_n$?  like how is $a_n$ computed in terms of all of the previous $a_{n-1}, \ a_{n-2}, ...$?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson https://mathoverflow.net/a/53402

Comment: well, thanks.  i sorta wish, if you would, to see the explicit recursion here.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, You definitely have such a recursion formula: $$ a_0 = 1, \qquad a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k+1}a_{n-k}, \qquad n \geq 1. $$

Comment: please @SangchulLee make this an answer so i can upvote it and checkmark it.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, As it was a low-hanging fruit from Argon's answer, I would like to give credit to him/her. :) Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: i guess i would like to see this low-hanging fruit ripen a bit from Argon's answer to get to yours.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \tan^ {-1} x = x-x^3/3 +x^5/5-x^7/7+.... =x(1-x^2/3 +x^4/5-x^6/7+...)$$

$$\frac {x}{ \tan ^{-1} x} = \frac {1}{1-x^2/3 +x^4/5-x^6/7+...}$$

You can get coefficients by long division.

For the first three terms I have $$\frac {1}{1-x^2/3 +x^4/5-x^6/7+...}=1+x^2/3-4x^4/45-... $$

Comment: can you get a recursion relationship that explicitly relates what the coefficient for the $x^{2n}$ term is as a function of the lower-order coefficients?  even if it has a summation in it?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I did not go that far, I just divided up to three terms. My guess is that a pattern will develop after few more terms.

Comment: i hadn't been seeing the pattern.  i don't think the next term is $x^6/12$, is it?

Comment: No, I do not think it was $x^6/12$. I think it was negative.   I

Comment: The third term is not correct. Using long division with more terms, you should get $$1+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{4 x^4}{45}+\frac{44 x^6}{945}-\frac{428
   x^8}{14175}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Wow, you have found many terms. My third term does not match with  yours but I am sure yours in correct.

Comment: I am a fanatic lover of Taylor series and Padé approximants (for almost 60 years).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Taylor series are amazing.